# Saxon s9 api not getting exposed using local jars in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, saxon

I want to include jar files locally in gradle, I have created a libs folder and added the jars there. the jars are added to the class path but I am not able to access the api.

my build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.github.lhotari.gradle-nar-plugin' version '0.5.1'
}

group 'com.acs.contentlake.nifi'
version '1.0'

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven {
        url("https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/apache-xerces/resolver")
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

compileJava{
    sourceCompatibility('8')
    targetCompatibility('8')
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.nifi', name: 'nifi-api', version: '1.15.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.nifi', name: 'nifi-utils', version: '1.15.0'
//    implementation group: 'net.sf.saxon', name: 'Saxon-HE', version: '10.6'
    implementation group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.9.1'
    implementation group: 'apache-xerces', name: 'resolver', version: '2.9.1'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.8'
//    implementation files('libs/saxon-ee-10.6.jar', 'icu4j-59.1.jar', 'jline-2.14.6.jar', 'saxon-ee-test-10.6.jar', 'saxon-sql-10.6.jar')
//    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    implementation name: 'saxon-ee-10.6'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: './libs/SaxonEE10-6J')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.nifi:nifi-mock:1.15.0'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I want to use Saxon-EE jars which are not available on any web repo.

I am unable to import

```
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.*;
```

If I use Saxon-HE then it is working fine, but I want to use the licensed edition which is not available on any web repo

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, `fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: './libs/SaxonEE10-6J')` isn't doing what you think it is. What I usually do at this point trying to debug Gradle files is create a "helloWorld" task that prints the classpath:

```
// Testing task for various Gradle debugging efforts
task helloWorld() {
  doLast {
    /*
    configurations.jsbuild.resolve().each { path ->
      println(path)
    }
     */
    println("Hello, world.")
  }
}
```

(Where you have to uncomment the lines and replace `jsbuild` with a local configuration that you derive from `implementation`. I don't think you can access the `implementation` classpath directly for reasons I doubt I fully understand.)

However, I can make this all much easier for you. Add this to your `repositories` closure:

```
  maven { url "https://dev.saxonica.com/maven" }
```

And then you can just load EE with Maven:

```
    implementation 'com.saxonica:Saxon-EE:10.6'
```